# how to get/know google calendarID and eventID

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm doing a tutorial for Google calendar so i can put it on my project..but it requires a Google calendarID so i can get events in my calendar my question is how or where do i get the calendarID and eventID?I'm doing the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId
```

this is where i should put the calendar id and event id

Answer (score 0):

Calendar ID is the email address of a calendar. If you want to access your primary calendar, you should use your email address. Otherwise you can find it in the web UI in the calendar settings page.

Another option is to perform a CalendarList.list() operation and check the emails there.

Similarly for events you can do a list operation on the Events collection and learn the IDs.